# Notice cookies still shown to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, css, cookies

is that the law of my country forces me to display a warning cookies on my website. I have placed this code in my web to display the message:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookies.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    if ($.cookie("acept_cookie") != 1) {
                        var i = 0;
                        $('.capa_cookie').show();

                        $(window).scroll(function (event) {
                            i++;
                            if (i > 1) {
                                $.cookie("acept_cookie", 1, { expires: 100 });
                                $('.capa_cookie').hide('slow');
                            }
                        });
                        $('table').click(function () {
                            $.cookie("acept_cookie", 1, { expires: 100 });
                            $('.capa_cookie').hide('slow');
                        });
                    }
                </script>


               <div class="capa_cookie hide">
                <div class="alert-pccom capa_cookie_interna ">
                    <strong>Pccomponentes.com</strong> utiliza cookies propias y de terceros para mejorar tu experiencia de
                    navegación y ofrecerte contenido y publicidad de tu interés. Al continuar navegando aceptas nuestra <a
                        href="politica_cookies.html" target="_blank"><strong>Política de Cookies</strong></a>.
                </div>
            </div>


   <style type="text/css">
                .capa_cookie {position: fixed;bottom: 0px;width: 100%;height: 50px;background-color: #f0f1f1;border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;}
                .capa_cookie_interna a{color: rgb(230, 112, 4);text-decoration: underline;}
                .capa_cookie_interna {position: relative;margin: 0 auto;width: 820px;height: 35px;font-size: 11.5px !important;}
                .alert-pccom {margin-top: 5px;background-color: rgb(247, 224, 200);border-color: rgb(235, 178, 79);color: rgb(230, 112, 4);padding: 2px 7px;line-height: 16px;}
            </style>
```

It works but when you refresh the page still appeared and this time is not removed and remains forever on the web. Any idea about the error? thanks

**WEB FOR SEE THE EXAMPLE:**

http://bolivar.uphero.com/

Comment: Since the accept cookie will be removed by the time the user scrolls down, you're basically re-setting that cookie everytime the page loads.

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon: Where is the cookie being removed? I only ever see it being checked (in one place) and added (in two others), never removed.

Comment: because it expires in 100 milliseconds. Also your .scroll function is in that if statement, which means it won't get executed on the second refresh, hence the message is never hidden. Move the .scroll function outside of that if statement.

Comment: En esta página se muestra el mismo mensaje con el mismo código que el usuario navega por el sitio se quita y no sale, en el supuesto de que el usuario ya ha aceptado las cookies. Pero a mi sitio para actualizar los servicios fijo y no desaparece como las primeras heladas de capa.

http://www.pccomponentes.com/

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon: Assuming she's using [this plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), that number is *days*, not milliseconds. And it's correct that the handlers for hiding the message are inside the `if` statement that checks whether the user has already accepted the message.

Comment: @Lusía: Todas las preguntas, comentarios y respuestas en Stack Overflow deben estar en Inglés, es una política del sitio. (All questions, comments, and answers on Stack Overflow must be in English, it's a site policy.)

Comment: Sure if anywhere I have shown works perfect, and not in mine is very strange, something must be failing.

Comment: This website works perfectly:

http://www.pccomponentes.com/